# Ploting a sequence into a graphic with maple

Tags: matrix, graph, maple

i've been asked to find the 10 vectors which is the result of MU, i now have to plot them into a graphic on maple. How am i supposed to do that ? i've tried to plot a sequence without success and i can't seem to find out how ? Thank for your help heres the code.

```
M := Matrix([[.94, 0.9e-1], [0.6e-1, .91]]);
                            [0.94  0.09]
                       M := [          ]
                            [0.06  0.91]
u0 := Vector([.8, .2]);
                                [0.8]
                          u0 := [   ]
                                [0.2]

i)



MU := seq(M^k . u0, k = 5 .. 50, 5);
      [0.688741062500000]  [0.639374880868144]  
MU := [                 ], [                 ], 
      [0.311258937500000]  [0.360625119131855]  

  [0.617470843820250]  [0.607751906216902]  [0.603439561970441]  
  [                 ], [                 ], [                 ], 
  [0.382529156179750]  [0.392248093783097]  [0.396560438029558]  

  [0.601526151918957]  [0.600677161714123]  [0.600300460249978]  
  [                 ], [                 ], [                 ], 
  [0.398473848081042]  [0.399322838285876]  [0.399699539750021]  

  [0.600133315809110]  [0.600059152932742]
  [                 ], [                 ]
  [0.399866684190889]  [0.399940847067257]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to get you started. (The last one is an animation. Left-click on it and press the play-button that appears near the menubar.)

```
restart;
M := Matrix([[.94, 0.9e-1], [0.6e-1, .91]]):
u0 := Vector([.8, .2]):

MU := seq(M^k . u0, k = 5 .. 50, 5):

plots:-pointplot([MU], style=pointline);
plots:-pointplot([MU], style=point);

datamat:=`<|>`(MU)^%T:

plots:-display(
  plot(datamat,style=line),
  plot(datamat,style=point,symbolsize=15,
       symbol=solidcircle,color=blue)
);

F:=proc(n::posint)
  plots:-pointplot([MU[1..n]], style=pointline);
end proc:
plots:-animate(F,[trunc(n)], n=1..10, frames=10, title=``);
```